# SWIFT_VERSION 3.2 is unsupported

Tags: swift, xcode

[image: Error]

I am getting this error in XCode, but it seems to have forgotten to tell me WHERE this reference is.   Clicking, double-clicking, right-clicking on these messages doesn't show me which file has this reference so I am lost as to how I am supposed to be able to find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in the build settings of your target, under **Swift Compiler - Language | Swift Language version**:

[image]

**Note**: But if your code was in Swift 3.2 and you change the language version to (for instance) 4.0, it won't compile, you'll probably need to rewrite or update some parts.